# Exploding MULTILINESTRING into individual segments in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, multipart, explode

I have a `MULTILINESTRING` in PostGIS consisting of several `LINESTRING`'s. Consider each `LINESTRING` to have a set of `POINT`'s

> P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>, ... P<sub>N</sub>

forming the line segments

> L<sub>1</sub>, L<sub>2</sub>, ... L<sub>N-1</sub>

where L<sub>X</sub> is the line segment connecting P<sub>X</sub> to P<sub>X+1</sub>.

**Using PostGIS 1.5 how can I explode the `MULTILINESTRING` into individual line segments of each `LINESTRING`?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two options come to mind. If you want a specific `LINESTRING` then you can use [ST_NumGeometries()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_NumGeometries.html) and [ST_GeometryN()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_GeometryN.html). Alternatively, if you want all the sub-geometries, [ST_Dump()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) is the way to go.

After actually reading the question, you will need to do something similar to [this](http://postgis.refractions.net/pipermail/postgis-users/2010-January/025818.html) post  from the *postgis-users* list:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText( ST_MakeLine(sp,ep) )
FROM
-- extract the endpoints for every 2-point line segment for each linestring
(SELECT
  ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) as sp,
  ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom)  )) as ep
FROM
   -- extract the individual linestrings
  (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(geom))).geom
   FROM mypolygontable
   -- eliminate 0 length linestring 
    where st_x(st_startpoint(geom))<> st_x(st_endpoint(geom))
   ) AS linestrings
) AS segments;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `st_dumpsegments`.
Example:

```
(st_dumpsegments((st_boundary(imo_.geom)))).geom
```