# Is there a st_buffer inverse function, that returns a width estimation?

Tags: buffer

When you supply a geometry `g1` and a width `w`  to the [standard OGC function](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfs) [ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html), 
it returns a new geometry `g2`,

```
  g2 = ST_Buffer(g1,w)
```

This question is about the inverse: a function where you can supply two related geometries — `g1` and `g2` satisfies [ST_Within(g1,g2)](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_DWithin.html) — and returns the width parameter,

```
  w = Unbuffer(g1,g2)
```

Now the interpretation of `w` is "average width".
So, **where is this function *Unbuffer* defined?  Are there references for it?  Is there a standard library for it?**

---

Complementing after bounty.

Examples of applications (estimation of): [street width](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/20279/7505), [sidewalk width](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33132/7505), river width, canal width, internal polygon semelhance, riparian vegetation buffer width, etc.

Example of proposals of credible sources:  [Pavelsky & Smith 2008](http://www.sscnet.ucla.edu/geog/downloads/297/326.pdf) ;  [ArcMap Script Procedure](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14264).  They are **not** solutions here because are (very) CPU consumer, "river-specialized", and *can not be implemented by OGC standards*. They calculate average of *river widthes* by each of many perpendicular (of a central line) lines; so, they are "brute force" algorithms.

Example of proposal *without* credible and/or official sources: [troubleshooter here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33158/7505). In this case, you  can get the bounty finding sources that makes credible the posted solution.

Comment: A possible answer, if no other post a better one here, is [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33158/7505).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ask, discuss, pay bounty, and post other variants of the same question... I decided to build my solution. It is not so generic as I want, but I am working...
There are 3 parts, corresponding to the 3 alternative kinds of `g1` inputs: point, line or polygon.

## Solution for point-buffer

From [my question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/34232/7505), about the width of the beach of a little island polygon.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION pointBuffer_width(g geometry, N integer DEFAULT 8) RETURNS float AS $$
   -- Returns the value of W in the approximation "g ~ ST_Buffer(ST_Centroid(g),W,'quad_segs=N')"
   -- where N>0 indicates the reference-shape, 1=square, 2=heptagon, ... circle.
   --
   SELECT sqrt(  area/(0.5*n*sin(2*pi()/n))  )
   FROM ( SELECT ST_Area($1) as area, 
                 (CASE WHEN $2<=1 THEN 4 ELSE 4*$2 END)::float as n
   ) as t;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL immutable;
```

## Solution for line-buffer

From [@celenius question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33158/7505), about the average width of a street.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION lineBuffer_width(
        -- rectangular strip mean width estimator
    p_len float,   -- len of the central line of g
    p_geom geometry, -- g
    p_btype varchar DEFAULT 'endcap=flat' -- st_buffer() parameter
) RETURNS float AS $f$
  DECLARE
    w_half float;
    w float;    
  BEGIN
         w_half := 0.25*ST_Area(p_geom)/p_len;
         w      := 0.50*ST_Area( ST_Buffer(p_geom,-w_half,p_btype) )/(p_len-2.0*w_half);
     RETURN w_half+w;
  END
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

## Solution for polygon-buffer

From [my first question about buffers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33132/7505), about estimation of the average width of a sidewalk...

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION polyBuffer_width(geometry, geometry) RETURNS float AS $$
   SELECT 2.0*(ST_Area($2)-ST_Area($1))/(st_perimeter($2)+st_perimeter($1));
$$ LANGUAGE SQL immutable;
```

## Putting it all together

(... WORKING ...)

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION buffer_width(
    -- Mean width estimator. Returns w_estim for approximates gbase~ST_Buffer(gref,w_estim) 
     gbase geometry, -- polygon that ST_Contains(gbase,gref)
     gref geometry DEFAULT NULL, -- point or line or NULL.
     len1 float DEFAULT 0.0, -- len gref, 0 if point, NULL if polygon. 
     N integer DEFAULT 8,  -- buffer parameter, quad_segs=N.
     bufferType varchar DEFAULT 'endcap=flat' -- st_buffer() parameter
) RETURNS float AS $f$
  DECLARE
     w_half float;
     w float;    
     aux float;    
     greftype varchar;
  BEGIN
   greftype := geometrytype(gbase);
   IF greftype LIKE '%LINE%' OR len1>0.0 THEN
       IF gref is not NULL THEN
          len1 = ST_Length(gref);
       END IF;
       w_half := 0.25*ST_Area(gbase)/len1;
       w := 0.50*ST_Area( ST_Buffer(gbase,-w_half,bufferType) )/(len1-2.0*w_half);
       RETURN w_half+w;
   ELSEIF greftype LIKE '%POINT%' OR gref IS NULL THEN
       aux = (CASE WHEN N<=1 THEN 4 ELSE 4*N END)::float;
       RETURN sqrt(  ST_Area(gbase)/(0.5*aux*sin(2.0*pi()/aux))  );
   ELSEIF greftype LIKE '%POLY%' THEN 
       RETURN 2.0*(ST_Area(gbase)-ST_Area(gref))/(st_perimeter(gbase)+st_perimeter(gref));
   ELSE
       RETURN -1.0; -- ERROR FLAG.
   END IF;
  END
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Overloads:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION buffer_width(  -- façade for point
     gbase geometry, 
     N integer
) RETURNS float AS $f$
     SELECT buffer_width($1,NULL,0.0,$2,'');
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION buffer_width(  -- façade for line
     len1 float,
     gbase geometry,
     bufferType varchar DEFAULT 'endcap=flat'
) RETURNS float AS $f$
     SELECT buffer_width($2,NULL,$1,8,$3);
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

## Testing

```sql
-- TEST-KIT FOR BUFFER-POINT
SELECT w, 
       (array['square','octagon','','','','','','~circle'])[shape] as shape, 
       round(buffer_width(circle8,shape),1) as circle8,
       round(buffer_width(octagon,shape),1) as octagon,
       round(buffer_width(square,shape),1) as square
FROM (
 SELECT
    w, shape, -- 1, 2, 3 or 10 
    ST_Buffer(g, w) as circle8, -- default 8, use 20 for perfect circle
    ST_Buffer(g, w, 'quad_segs=2') as octagon,
    ST_Buffer(g, w, 'quad_segs=1') as square
 FROM ( SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)') as g,  
        unnest(array[1.0,150.0]) as w,
        unnest(array[1,2,8]) as shape    
      ) as t
) as t2;


 -- TEST-KIT FOR BUFFER-LINE
 SELECT *, round(100.0*(w_estim-w)/w,1) as estim_perc_error
 FROM (
        SELECT btype, round(len,1) AS len, w, round(w/len,3) AS wfactor,
               round(  buffer_width(len, gbase, btype)  ,2) as w_estim ,
               round(  0.5*ST_Area(gbase)/len       ,2) as w_near
        FROM (
         SELECT
            *, st_length(g) AS len, ST_Buffer(g, w, btype) AS gbase
         FROM (
               -- SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(50 50,150 150)') AS g, -- straight
               SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(50 50,150 150,150 50,250 250)') AS g,
            unnest(array[1.0,10.0,20.0,50.0]) AS w
              ) AS t, 
             (SELECT unnest(array['endcap=flat','endcap=flat join=bevel']) AS btype
             ) AS t2
        ) as t3
  ) as t4;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in Postgis, but I thinks this might work:

```
ST_Distance(ST_Boundary(g2),g1)
```

The [ST_Boundary](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Boundary.html) will transform your Polygon into a Linestring, If g2 was the result of a X distance buffer from g1, then all the vertices of the resulting linestring must be at the same distance X of g1, and [ST_Distance](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance.html) (minimun distance) will give you the desired result.

**NOTE:** This won't work with buffers generated from [ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) with join=benvel or encap=flat.

To resolve the problem with the benvel and the flat. Here my two cents, you could transform the g1 linestring or polygon to the n line segments (Ls) that compose it with this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21648/explode-multilinestring-into-individual-segments-in-postgis-1-5), them calculate for each of them the distance of its middle points to g2 with:

```
ST_Distance(ST_Boundary(g2),line_interpolate_point(Ls,0.5))
```

And finally calculate the [Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29) of all the those distances.

Assuming that your g1 geometry is not too complex, the mode will give you the exact width of the original buffer, while the mean will give always an aproximation.

Comment: I appreciate your geometric reasoning, your `ST_Distance(ST_Boundary(g2),g1)` solution is useful as a reliable measure of *minimum width*. But the question is about "*average width*"... Your idea can be translated/optimized as the `(ST_perimeter(g2) - ST_perimeter(g1))/8.0` estimator, when g1 and g2 are rectangular. A complex calculus, using average of [minimum distantes was used here](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14264).

Comment: For a non benvel ou flat encap buffer the minimum width will be the same as the exact width, and the same as the average width. I'm not sure if I understand what is your final objective for this question, clarifying that might help to improve the answers. Is the g2 geometry really a result of a buffer operation? Or is an independent polygon from g1 and you want to find out the most aproximate buffer of g1, by finding the w average width? What do you mean by deal with endcap/benvel join? Can you show\draw the worst case scenario of g1 and g2 geometries?

Comment: About use of [split line](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/21648/7505), ok, please complete your answer with a complete function, is  possible as a "brute force algorithm" (!). Please also post sources/references, if you have... But, before, check if I understand: if you simulate with ST_Buffer, and test with your minimum distance, of course, it is the same value than average. But check **real cases**, see the *river width* application example (see my refs) or the real case of street width, or any other... The **real life need averages (!)**.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to get vertices from the polygon (buffer result) , using the vertices as input for [voronoi polygons](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgresql_plr_tut02)  , these polygons draws the mid line between the vertices, then try to extract the mid line, by erasing the lines which touches the (buffer result) contour.

i wish it could help

Comment: I understand that for PostGIS the  Voronoi function is only a [item of WishList](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiWishList)...      http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1215

Comment: so sorry, i've never used tried this in postgis, but this link could help you to run voronoi polygons in postgis http://geogeek.garnix.org/2010/09/voronoi-diagrams-in-postgis.html

Comment: Ops, sorry truncated comments. Thanks about links, I need do some homework with them.

Comment: search for this paragraph "Thiessen polygon coverage" in this link   https://portal.opengeospatial.org/modules/admin/license_agreement.php?suppressHeaders=0&access_license_id=3&target=http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/%3fartifact_id=19820

Comment: Hum.... Ok, now I understand a bit more of your answer... Perhaps you have confused the "geometric inverse" with "inverse for obtain the radius". In the question we not need to generate a central line geometry (we have it as g1 parameter), or skeleton, we need only a float number that represents the "average width", that was the buffer radius (that produced an approximation to g2).

Comment: Simon Greener posted a function to the PostGIS list a few days ago to create voronoi polygons.

Comment: try to get lines from g2 then apply near tool http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000 , between g1 and g2_lines