# What is the width of the beach of a little island polygon?

Tags: buffer

This is a "classic" problem, **that have no practical utility** (see note-1 for applications), but illustrate another GIS problems...

[image: little island figure]

We can do some approximations to modeling the situation,

- the real center (coconut) is not at the ST_Centroid point, but can be approximated to;
- the real shape (a island) is not a circle, neither a square, they are optional references.

So, **translating the question to an equation**, and using OGC standard functions... "**What is the value of *w*?**" at the equation

```
ST_Area(ST_Buffer(ST_Centroid(littleIsland), w, quad_segs)) = ST_Area(littleIsland)
```

When `quad_segs=1`, the reference is a square, when `quad_segs>=8` the reference is near to a circle (see examples of [generated polygons](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html)).

---

NOTE-1: For understand this problem into a context of applications, 
see "[Is there a st_buffer inverse function, that returns a width estimation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33312/7505)" and 
see "[How to fit a polygon to a “best buffer” about a reference geometry in it?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/34260/7505)".

NOTE-2: the "inverse function" is so general and complex, because can operates with point, line and polygon inputs. Here we can discuss the simplest case, when the input is like a point, with no area or length.

Comment: depends if it is high tide or low tide....

Comment: Yes ;-)  Sorry about the "no practical utility" of my *little beach*... Well, with a real beach you need also the slope... And a really useful model need a function that transforms time into tide height.

Comment: What, precisely, is the question? All we have is a picture. Do you seek some distinguished point within a polygon? If so, what property distinguishes it? *E.g.,* should it (a) be furthest from all exterior points; (b) minimize some average function of distance over the polygon (*e.g.*, the centroid minimizes the squared distance); (c) the center of a minimal bounding circle/rectangle/ellipse/some other shape; (d) minimize some average function of distance *to the boundary*; (e) the center of a maximal inscribed circle/rectangle/triangle; etc., etc?

Comment: Sorry my english, you can edit it... The question is "*What is the best estimated mean width, `w`, for a given reference-shape (ex. square or circle)?*", where "best estimation" supply equal areas, the `ST_Area(st_buffer(point,bestW,shape))` and the `ST_Area(island)`. My answer below, complements my descriptions... About "best fit" see [this complementary question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/34260/7505).

Comment: It is still *very* difficult to determine what you are trying to do. The calculations appear to determine the radius of a circle of a specified area and the side of a square of specified area. What GIS problem does that solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using this function to solve the problem, but not have any source/reference (do you have? please inform posting a comment)... So, I posted also demonstrations and tests.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION pointbuffer_width(g geometry, N integer DEFAULT 8) RETURNS float AS $$
   -- Returns the value of W in the approximation "g ~ ST_Buffer(ST_Centroid(g),W,'quad_segs=N')"
   -- where N>0 indicates the reference-shape, 1=square, 2=heptagon, ... circle.
   --
   SELECT sqrt(  area/(0.5*n*sin(2*pi()/n))  )
   FROM ( SELECT ST_Area($1) as area, 
                 (CASE WHEN $2<=1 THEN 4 ELSE 4*$2 END)::float as n
   ) as t;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL immutable;
```

---

### DEMONSTRATING

The main shapes, *circle* and *square*, have areas

```
A = pi*w^2   # circle with radius w
A = 2*w^2    # square circumscribed into a circle of radius w
```

The intermediary shapes are the regular polygons of `n` sides. The square have `n`=4, the octagon `n`=8, etc. So, we can substitute the factor of `w^2` by a function `f(n)` that supply the adequate value for the `n` sides.
The formula of the [area of a regular polygon of `n` sides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Area) with a [circumradius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumradius) `w`, is:

```
 A = 0.5*n*sin(2*pi/n)*w^2
```

Where we can check: for `n=4` the factor `0.5*n*sin(2*pi/n)` is *2*; for `n=400` (infinite) is *3.14* (~pi).

For the standard `ST_Buffer(g,'quad_segs=N')` polygon generator we can check that this `N` is `4*n`.

[image: different buffers]

Confirmation of `N=4*n` with PostGIS:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsEWKT((p_geom).geom) As geom_ewkt
  FROM (SELECT ST_DumpPoints( 
      ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)'),50,'quad_segs=5') 
 ) AS p_geom )  AS t;
```

It returns 4+1 rows when N=1, 20+1 rows when N=5, etc. The dumped last row repeat the first, to close the polygon.

### TESTING

Tests simulating buffers (need more tests with irregular ones)

```sql
-- FORMULA TESTER FOR POINTS AND ITS BUFFERS:
SELECT w, 
       (array['square','octagon','','','','','','~circle'])[shape] as shape, 
       round(pointbuffer_width(circle8,shape),1) as circle8,
       round(pointbuffer_width(octagon,shape),1) as octagon,
       round(pointbuffer_width(square,shape),1) as square
FROM (
 SELECT
    w, shape, -- 1, 2, 3 or 10 
    ST_Buffer(g, w) as circle8, -- default 8, use 20 for perfect circle
    ST_Buffer(g, w, 'quad_segs=2') as octagon,
    ST_Buffer(g, w, 'quad_segs=1') as square
 FROM ( SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)') as g,  
        unnest(array[1.0,150.0]) as w,
        unnest(array[1,2,8]) as shape    
      ) as t
 ) as t2;
```

**RESULTS**:

```
   w   |  shape  | circle8 | octagon | square 
-------+---------+---------+---------+--------
   1.0 | square  |     1.2 |     1.2 |     *1
 150.0 | octagon |   157.6 |    *150 |  126.1
   1.0 | ~circle |      *1 |       1 |    0.8
 150.0 | square  |   187.4 |   178.4 |   *150
   1.0 | octagon |     1.1 |      *1 |    0.8
 150.0 | ~circle |    *150 |   142.8 |  120.1
```

**Conclusion**: it is stable for any w value (!); it is exact when the modeled shape fits the geometry shape (*).