# How to fit a polygon to a "best buffer" about a reference geometry in it?

Tags: buffer, spatial-statistics

If I have a polygonal geometry `gbase`, like [a street](http://gis.cambridgema.gov/DataDictionary/Datapages/..%5Cimages%5Cpavedsurfaces.jpg) (a rectangular strip), and a reference geometry `gref`, like a central line of `gbase`. The question is what is the function (here named ***BestBuffer***) that returns a geometry `gbest`,

```
gbest = BestBuffer(gbase, gref [,p])
```

that is the "best fit" for `gbase` and can be generated from `gref` by a [ST_Buffer](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) (optionally with a shape parametrized by `p`)?

## Remarks

Formally this is a  [mathematical optimization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization):

*Given*: inputs `gref` and `gbase` (optional `p`) and,

```
gbest = ST_Buffer(gref,w,p)
```

*Sought*: parameter **`w`** that supply

```
ST_Area(gbest) = ST_Area(gbase)
```

---

NOTE: I think `BestBuffer` can be a "standard library" function (where is it? please show sources/references), not a external plugin, because the estimation checks are all standard OGC build-in functions.

---

## ILLUSTRATIONS

### BestBuffer when gref is a POINT

Illustrating by the trivial case, the *buffer of point*, that have exact solution:

[image]

is the same as "*fit a polygon to a square of equal area*" (or a circle).

*Inputs*: `gbase` a (blue) island, `gref` is only a point, `gref=ST_Centroid(gbase)`, or another position, and the parameter N, that can be 1 for square and 8 for circle.

*Results* (pink):

```
  gbest_square = bestBuffer(gbase,ST_Centroid(gbase),1);
  gbest_circle = bestBuffer(gbase,anotherpoint,8);
```

You can approximate `gbase` to `gbest` without change original area.

---

### BestBuffer when gref is a LINE

Illustrating with the  Massachusetts avenue,

[image: the Massachusetts avenue]

[image: gbase and gref]

*Inputs*: `gbase`, a polygon of a street, `gref` a (blue) center line in it, and the choice of shape (no endcaps)

*Result* of   `gbest=bestBuffer(gbase,gref,'endcap=flat')`

[image: gbest]

is a rectangle (`gbest`). It is the "*best buffer about `gref`*" for Massachusetts avenue, filling the same area as `gbase`.

Another cases where you may need to draw *BestBuffer* of polygons and its central lines: when need to show  [streets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/20279/7505), [sidewalks](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33132/7505), rivers, etc. with *uniform  width*, instead real/irregular ones.

---

### BestBuffer when gref is a POLYGON

[image]

In the above illustration, the blue polygon represents a island with your beach, as `gbase`, and `gref` the same island without the beach. `gbest0` is the "best buffer" for `gbase`.

*Inputs*: `gbase` (blue), `gref` a (gray). Can be rendered as `ST_Difference(gbase,gref)`, that represent beachs.

*Result*:   `gbest0=bestBuffer(gbase,gref)`, but we want to render as (`gbest`),

```
  gbest =  ST_Difference(gbest0,gref)
```

The goal of the buffer of `gref` is to generate the "beach geometry", even if `gbest` not generates an exact `gbase-gref` geometry: it is a good approximation and have uniform width *w*, the average width of `gbase-gref` (*w* **is** *mean beach width*).

---

## NOTES

Fit the "best curve" about a set of points in an XY chart is a classical statiscal problem,
have classical solutions, and have a lot of tools for it.
Similarly the "best curve about another curve" is usual when the "best" is a simple one,
like a straight line, a parabola, etc.  To fit irregular/complex lines
[Cubic spline lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) are frequently used.

Where are the standard functions tools for "fit the best polygon in a GIS context"?  Are there standard libraries?  For generic statistical problems we have external packages
that can be integrated with postgreSQL and PostGIS...

But for built-in functions: `ST_Buffer` is a standard function, why not a function  `BestBuffer` in a complementary library?

Comment: Despite the length and detail of this question, I am unable to find a definition or even a clear description of what `BestBuffer` is supposed to do. Could you perhaps give an example?

Comment: Thanks, I edited and add figures for better description.

Comment: I still cannot discern a definite problem here. You state, "The goal of the buffer of gref is to generate the beach geometry." Obviously that cannot be done without additional information; for instance, it sounds like you are asking to negatively buffer a polygon and that requires you to stipulate the buffer distance. What, precisely, do you hope the inputs and outputs of your procedure to be?

Comment: Ok, editing: now I am illustrating at first paragraphs, inputs and outputs.

Comment: Thank you; it is becoming clearer with your example of Massachusetts Avenue. But in what sense is this rectangle "best"? It's not even a true buffer (the ends are clipped instead of rounded) and it seems likely that the buffer of a slightly nonlinear curve might match the original polygon a little better.

Comment: Please check the use of the parameter 'endcap=flat' on standard OGC ST_Buffer function. With PostGIS it is a rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  **if** we have a good solution for [**this other problem**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33312/7505)
(it supplies a `buffer_width` estimation function) we will also have a simple solution here.

### Possible solution when `gref` is a POLYGON

Using the example of the question illustration,

```
wbest  = buffer_width(gbase,gref,p); -- estimation
gbest0 = ST_Buffer(gref,wbest,p);
gbest  = ST_Difference(gbest0,gref);
```

where to use the optional parameter`p`, you must have a *a priory* knowledge about the buffer shape/style (like parameters quad_seg, endcap, and join).

### Solution when `gref` is a LINE and `gbase` a strip

There are restrictions for a generalized use, but is stable for strips (shapes near to a "rectangular strip").

```
wbest = buffer_width(gbase,gref,0.0,'endcap=flat'); -- estimation
gbest = ST_Buffer(gref,wbest,'endcap=flat');
```

See question illustration for details.

### Solution solution when `gref` is a POINT

For this trivial case (buffering a central point) a solution exists (!):

```
gbest = ST_Buffer(ST_Centroid(gbase),buffer_width(gbase,quad_segs),quad_segs)
```

where the `buffer_width` function is the [**best average width estimator for point-buffers**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/34232/7505); and `quad_segs` is a "shape factor" (default is a circle).
Below piece of code with a concrete example:

```sql
SELECT buffer_width(ST_GeomFromText(
  'POLYGON((150 90,130 54,100 40,63 53,50 90,40 124,99 140,155 126,150 90))'
),2); -- 53.6
SELECT ST_Area(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)'),53.6,'quad_segs=2'));
      -- 8126
SELECT ST_Area(ST_GeomFromText(
  'POLYGON((150 90,130 54,100 40,63 53,50 90,40 124,99 140,155 126,150 90))')
);    -- 8126
```

the polygon is a very deformated octagon, but the buffer generates a regular octagon with the same area, by `w=53.6`  estimated by the `buffer_width` function.