# Merging a LineString with a MultiLineString

Tags: shapely

Is it possible to use shapely or some other python software to merge a LineString with a MultiLineString?

Shapely's `ops.linemerge` fails here.

I am attempting to merge segments of the same road, represented in different rows of the NYC streets dataset, some as LineStrings and others as MultiLineStrings. Specifically, I am using the `DCM_StreetCenterLine` from:

https://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/dwn-digital-city-map.page

Answer (score 1):

The [shapely manual](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) seems to suggest that you can merge LineString and MultiLineString. An approach that may work (untested) is to explode the MultiLinestring into its constituent LineStrings, you then run the merge on just all Linestrings? How to explode a MultiLineString is discussed in several ways in this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104312/multilinestring-to-separate-individual-lines-using-python-with-gdal-ogr-fiona).